# Working with audio in the web

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, audioeffect

Hey Guys I need some hints or resources how to work with audio through the web.

Basic scenario: Someone turn on his microphone and starts recording his song. After this is done he may want to add some sound effects.

Is this even possible? I have no glue where to start. Maybe you can suggest some tools or even npm packages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [webRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) ? look over this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

Comment: Never seen before… thanks for that! But what about sound effects. Am I able to modify the recorded sound after?

Comment: Not sure you if it supported by webrtc but you can make a P2P connection and send audio/video